# need query for this logic

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

The table A looks like

| number | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 122.3 | 30-JUN-21 |
| 100 | 152.3 | 31-DEC-21 |
| 100 | 122.3 | 20-JUN-21 |
| 100 | 122.3 | 30-JUN-22 |
| 122 | 132.3 | 30-JUN-21 |
| 122 | 142.3 | 31-DEC-21 |
| 142 | 132.3 | 20-JUN-21 |
| 142 | 152.3 | 30-JUN-22 |

and the output of query should look like..

| number | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 244.6 | 20-JUN-21 |
| 122 | 132.3 | 30-JUN-21 |
| 142 | 132.3 | 20-JUN-21 |

The agenda is to sum the amount by taking minimum of date group by number and if some other date exists in same minimum month that also has to be included.Can anyone help me with the query?

```
select sum(amount),min(date) from A group by number;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Do you really use MySQL? the data looks like OracleDB data...

Comment: Group by DATE_TRUNC('month', date) additionally, then enumerate over a number ordered by truncated date and select only 1st rows.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a subquery that gets the minimum date for each number. Then join that with the table to get all the rows in the same month and number, and sum the amounts.

```
SELECT t1.number, SUM(t1.amount) AS amount, t2.date
FROM A AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT number, MIN(date) AS date
    FROM A
    GROUP BY number
) AS t2 ON t1.number = t2.number AND YEAR(t1.date) = YEAR(t2.date) AND MONTH(t1.date) = MONTH(t2.date)
GROUP BY t1.number
```

[DEMO](http://SELECT%20t1.number,%20SUM(t1.amount)%20AS%20amount,%20t2.date%20FROM%20A%20AS%20t1%20JOIN%20(%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20number,%20MIN(date)%20AS%20date%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20A%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20number%20)%20AS%20t2%20ON%20t1.number%20=%20t2.number%20AND%20YEAR(t1.date)%20=%20YEAR(t2.date)%20AND%20MONTH(t1.date)%20=%20MONTH(t2.date)%20GROUP%20BY%20t1.number)